# Determine if SHIFT is pressed insde keyboard Hook Proc

Tags: delphi, hook

inside my hook proc, how can i determine whether a used is pressing SHIFT (without releasing it) and then a char key (like A) ?

for example, if i press Shift+A, i want to know that it will be an uppercase a instead of getting it like Shift, a

so it will be A, if a user presses and releases Shift, it will capture Shift only.

the instaleld hook is WH_KEYBOARD (Global)

```
function KeyHookProc(Code: Integer; wVirtKey: WPARAM; lKeyStroke: LPARAM)
  : LRESULT; stdcall;
type
  TTransitionState = (tsPressed, tsReleased);

  PKeystrokeData = ^TKeystrokeData;

  TKeystrokeData = record
    VirtualKey: WPARAM;
    KeyStroke: LPARAM;
    KeyState: TKeyboardState;
  end;
var
  Transition: TTransitionState;
  KeystrokeDataPtr: PKeystrokeData;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hKeyHook, Code, wVirtKey, lKeyStroke);

  Transition := TTransitionState((lKeyStroke shr 31) and 1);

  if (Code = HC_ACTION) and (Transition = tsPressed) then
  begin
    New(KeystrokeDataPtr);
    try
      KeystrokeDataPtr^.VirtualKey := wVirtKey;
      KeystrokeDataPtr^.KeyStroke := lKeyStroke;
      GetKeyboardState(KeystrokeDataPtr^.KeyState);
      SendMessage(hConsole, WM_NULL, 0, LPARAM(KeystrokeDataPtr));
    finally
      Dispose(KeystrokeDataPtr);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This class should provide the needed informations.  http://wwww.bummisoft.de/download/Key_Hook_Class.zip

Comment: btw, isn't global hooks suppouse to be inside .dll ? from my recollection LowLevel one doesn't have to be inside a .dll though, am i correct ?

Comment: @user1803300 That is correct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i wonder how his hook works perfectly inside an .exe.

Comment: Hard to imagine why that would be so.

Comment: @bummi can you make it support unicode ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code we use in normal day-to-day use to detect the shift key. I've never used it in a hooked context, so I don't know if it would work there, or if something is different in that context that would prevent it.

```
function ShiftIsDown : Boolean;
var
  State: TKeyboardState;
begin
  WINDOWS.GetKeyboardState(State);
  Result := ((State[vk_Shift] and 128) <> 0);
end;
```

Comment: i am familiar with this code, bu..t i want to extract this info from lParam, is it possible :S ?

Comment: Be careful of temporal issues here.  `GetKeyboardState` returns the *current* state of the keyboard.  If the user has released or pressed the SHIFT key in between the keystroke that generated the message in question and the message handler being executed--which can be a non-trivial amount of time in some situations--this will give inaccurate results.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Have you got that right?  *An application can call this function to retrieve the current status of all the virtual keys. The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads.*

Comment: @David: Yes, that's right.  The CURRENT status of the keys, which changes when messages are removed from the queue.  Imagine that someone pressed SHIFT-A, generating the message, which, for whatever reason, did not get removed from the message queue and processed until half a second later, by which time the user had released the SHIFT key.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Which leads to the behaviour that the user expects. The letter a or A will be produced dependent on the state of the SHIFT key at the time that the A key was pressed, and not dependent on the state of the SHIFT key at the time that the message was processed.

Comment: @Robert FWIW your normal day-to-day code is needlessly complex. Your function should read: `function ShiftKeyDown: Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0;
end;
`

Comment: @David: I really think that's the opposite of what it's saying.  You can't get information about what the keyboard state *used to be* at some arbitrary point in the past, without something to identify that past point as part of the function input.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You are not getting information about an arbitrary point in the past. You are getting information about the state when the message was posted. Have a look at the contrast between `GetKeyState` and `GetAsyncKeyState`. The other similar issue crops up with `GetMessagePos` and `GetCursorPos`.

Comment: GetKeyboardState should not be called inside hook proc

Comment: @user539484 I was dubious about that. But I don't know what happens when you do so. What does happen?

Answer (score 0):

You detect the pressing of the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key when your hook proc is called with `wParam` equal to `VK_SHIFT`.

When your hook proc is called corresponding to the <kbd>A</kbd> key being pressed, the `wParam` and `lParam` values are identical whether or not the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key is down. Since you are not calling `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` as would happen in a normal message loop, you are going to have to translate the raw key down/up events into actual key presses.

It's probably going to be easiest for you to use `GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)<0` to detect whether or not the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key is down. That depends on exactly what you are trying to do. It looks a little like you are making a fully functioned keylogger. In which case ad-hoc calls to `GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)<0` may not meet your needs, and proper processing of the individual key down/up messages would be better.

---

Some other comments:

1. Why are you heap allocating your `TKeystrokeData` record? You can perfectly well use a stack allocated record.
2. I hope that `hConsole` is a window in the same process as your hook. If not it won't receive any useful information because the pointer you send it is only meaningful in the process that defines it. If you want to send information cross-process them `WM_COPYDATA` is your guy.

Comment: I found out something REALLY weird..., my keyboard has 2 languages, English and Hebrew, now, when i set focus on Notepad and change it to Hebrew and start typing random letters, the hook captures English letters (i see it in TMemo), when i set focus on the TMemo and change it to hebrew, then going back to notepad and writing again, it then captures Hebrew, why is this happening ? (could it be keyboard layout something?) 

   P.S - I changed it through the Language Bar.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that other question.