# GetKeyboardLayoutName of another process?

Tags: delphi, winapi, keyboard-layout

is there an extended (Ex) version of GetKeyboardLayoutName which gets the current keyboard language of another process ? becuase if i call GetKeyboardLayoutName in a simple project, it shows me the selected language of the current process, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear why you need this information since there is nothing you can meaningfully do with it anyway. Let the app have its keyboard layout.

Comment: @RaymondChen does it matter ? for me it does. thank you.

Comment: Describe your problem where you think getting the keyboard layout of another process is the solution. Since you cannot get the keyboard layout of another process, we will have to solve your problem some other way.

Comment: @RaymondChen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385466/determine-if-shift-is-pressed-insde-keyboard-hook-proc i asked about a hook, now in order for me to make it support unicode, i need to get the foreground (active) window keyboard layout to pass it to ToUnicodeEx.

Comment: If you have a hook, then you are already in the other process. Do the work directly there. Also, it's not clear why you are writing a keylogger. Why not just an existing one?

Comment: @RaymondChen it's a Lowlevel keyboard hook, will it work ? (Global, but not in a .dll)

Comment: @RaymondChen I just tried your suggestion and it's not working, i call GetKeyboardLayoutName inside the hook proc and use Outputdebugstring and it's still the same, it's probably just being called, not injected to other processes.

Comment: Low level hooks are not injected. Switch to an injecting hook. Note that your app may end up getting flagged as malware since it is basically a keylogger.

Comment: @RaymondChen i just tried it with an injecting .dll, still not working correctly.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your hook.